# Can I install only one version of Android and get the same results as I would with different versions?

Tags: android

I have installed only JellyBean in Android Studio. Can my app give me the same results other versions of Android would or should I install all versions and then check my app with each?

Comment: how can you install JellyBean in android studio ?

Comment: It will give same result below API JellyBean but for Higher version you have to install another version

Comment: Upto JellyBean it will give the same output ???

Comment: Yes, upto JellyBean it will give same result